# How does malware come in to a PC from USB?

Tags: malware

I know that there are many routes that malware comes in to a PC.
One of them is USB or HDD, but I am not sure how it works on those devices.

First af all, how is malware embedded into a device? 
What's the possibility that malware comes in to USB/HDDs?
If I had bought some USB device in a shop and I used it to store some my data in my PC, then malware comes in to my PC?

Who is the malicious user that embeds malware into a USB?

Comment: Not quite sure this question makes sense: "USB" means "universal serial bus", and it's used to connect things like mice, keyboards, webcams, … but also things like mass storage devices, for example, external hard drives. "HDD" typically stands for "hard disk drive". And as such, you're comparing a bus to a type of storage medium that can be connected in a large number of different ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### USB Device’s Firmware

There's also proof that malicious firmware could also cause harm and that a firmware could be infected by a computer. *Chris Hoffman*'s [article](https://www.howtogeek.com/203061/don%E2%80%99t-panic-but-all-usb-devices-have-a-massive-security-problem/) on *How-To Geek* explains this in detail, but here's the part that answers your guestion: USB device can claim to be a flash drive, a keyboard, and network adapter — even at the same time!

> The key to this problem is the design goal that USB devices could do
>   many different things. For example, a USB flash drive with malicious
>   firmware could function as a USB keyboard. When you connect it to your
>   computer, it could send keyboard-press actions to the computer as if
>   someone sitting at the computer were typing the keys. Thanks to keyboard shortcuts, a malicious firmware functioning as a keyboard could—for example—open a Command Prompt window, download a program from a remote server, run it, and agree to a UAC prompt.

---

### Windows AutoRun

The major threat was imposed by the [AutoRun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AutoRun) feature first introduced in Windows 95 that allows removable media to launch programs without user consent. Another [article](https://www.howtogeek.com/203522/how-autorun-malware-became-a-problem-on-windows-and-how-it-was-mostly-fixed/) by *Chris Hoffman* has more detailed information an examples on this.

Since Windows Vista this functionality has been disabled by default, replaced by AutoPlay dialogue. Windows 7 removed Autorun for every device type except CDROM, but it's possible to spoof this information, and AutoPlay can still be trickered manually.

AutoRun can be turned off for every device type with a registry tweak:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\policies\Explorer]
"NoDriveTypeAutoRun"=dword:000000ff
```

The feature works from a text file, [`autorun.inf`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autorun.inf), at the root of the inserted file system. Back then I created a simple CD-ROM that took advantage of the feature by using AutoRun to disable AutoRun for good. The registry modification above was in `autorun-off.reg` called from this `autorun.inf`:

```
[autorun] 
open=%systemroot%\regedit.exe /s autorun-off.reg
```

Comment: Interesting! Thanks! By the way, do you know who embeds malware into USB?

Comment: @mallea What do you mean, "who embeds malware into USB"? Are you looking for an anecdote or a class of adversaries or what?

Comment: @forest Thank you for your clarification. What I mean by "who" is a class of adversaries.

Comment: That's a pretty broad question. Depending on the exploitation vector, it can range from a pentester to an APT. Generally it involves an adversary in close physical proximity or with easy physical access to you (a business competitor, a government agency, a penetration tester, etc). A scammer on the other side of the world or a botnet owner would not fall into any of those categories.